# Access denied, Running .py on Apache2 try to open file from /opt on Apache2

Tags: python, ubuntu, apache2

I have problem with permission. I'm running .py program with CGI on Apache2 /var/www/html/project, on .py program i try to open file in /opt/image.png i got :

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/image.png
```

Apache2 configure:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName localhost

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory /var/www/html/project>
            Order Allow,Deny
            Allow from all
            Options +ExecCGI
            AddHandler cgi-script .py
        </Directory>

<Directory "/opt">
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

The code, i get the path with POST from outside:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-# enable debugging

print("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8")
print()

import cgitb, cgi
cgitb.enable()

import PIL

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

file = form.getvalue('file')

imopen = Image.open(file)
```

I have try to change modifier to 777, owner to root i still can't access and permission denied. I think the problem is i can't access from /var to /opt ? any clue ? Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the code where you are getting the PNG?

Comment: I'm edit on the question from the code, Thank you..